# Windows 11 does "system reset" when trying to boot from external USB

Tags: windows, boot, external-hard-drive, windows-11, system-restore

I have a HP Windows 11 laptop. I made a live fully installed USB with Ubuntu on it. The USB is tested on Linux machines and it boots nicely, no problems.

On the Windows 11 device (with HP Wolf Security), `the laptop goes immediately into "system reset" when I aim to boot from the external USB`. It then restarts and boots into Windows again.

I am sure it has to do with some Windows 11 mechanism that "blocks" booting from external drives (hence the "system reset") or HP Wolf Security makes this problem? P.S. Disabling "secure boot" does not change anything.

Comment: Did you have to set Security Boot off to use the Ext USB?   That would definitely cause issues with Windows 11.   Use a Virtual Machine for your idea instead.

Comment: @John - no need to turn off Secure Boot. The ext USB should work (it does on my Linux machines). The ext USB also get recognised correctly (UEFI). Why would the "system reset" immediately after selecting to boot from the ext USB? I would expect other "errors" than that if something were wrong either with the ext USB or in the BIOS.

Comment: I am not sure why that should occur. No issue with bland external drives. Use Virtual Machines for a different OS.

Comment: This absolutely is the fault of HP Wolf Security not Windows, as Windows 11, does not have a feature that would cause this behavior. Windows 11 requires Secure Boot, and is also, not the reason for this behavior.